# Regex string must contain specific value and one or more of 3 other values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex to use on Cloudpath.net's captive portal to check if a user is a member of certain groups.

The user must be a member of "WiFi Access" and must then be a member of one or more of the following groups: Pupils, Staff, IT Support.

I've written the following which works on an online regex tester with all of the groups on one line, but doesn't work on the captive portal:

```
(?=.*\bWiFi\sAccess\b)(?=.*\bPupils\b|.*\bStaff\b|.*\bIT\sSupport\b)
```

I thought maybe the groups are listed one per line so I tried the following two expressions:

```
(?=[.\n]*\bWiFi\sAccess\b)(?=[.\n]*\bPupils\b|[.\n]*\bStaff\b|[.\n]*\bIT\sSupport\b)
/(?=.*\bWiFi\sAccess\b)(?=.*\bPupils\b|.*\bStaff\b|.*\bIT\sSupport\b)/s
```

But neither of those work either (I'm not sure that I've written it correctly). I don't even know if the captive portal is using PCRE or POSIX.

Does anybody have any suggestions I could try please?

Comment: Can you output the string you're trying to match against and copy it here?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have the ability to output it. I know every group name because I can see them in Active Directory, but I don't know what format Cloudpath store the list in.

Answer (score 1):

This regex may work for you, if all the group names are in the same string. I would make sure the `i` (case-insensitive) flag is on, for whatever language you're using.

```
^(?=[\s\S]*\bWiFi\s*Access\b)(?=[\s\S]*\b(?:Pupils|Staff|IT\s*Support)\b).+
```

One easy way to permit everything is to use a character class and the negated character class (capital letter), like `[\s\S]*`.

I changed the `\s` you're using in the middle of group names to `\s*` which permits any number of whitespace characters (including 0). It's not the best option for a final solution but it might help you debug. I would fiddle with it and find that actual whitespace component and match it literally.

A step you can take in debugging is to remove the `\b` word boundaries from the regex (only as a debugging step).

```
^(?=[\s\S]*WiFi\s*Access)(?=[\s\S]*(?:Pupils|Staff|IT\s*Support)).+
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately even the second expression you suggested trying doesn't work. I'm now starting to wonder if the values are stored in an array and they regex each item individually, as that expression should match anything containing those values. The only example they provide is "Group1|Group2|Group3".